# Delete comments in a Workitem Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a bulk of workitem in azuredevops project. I want do delete the comments inside all of them, even the comments raised by others. Is there a way to do it? I tried with delete comments api and it gives me an error: VS403664: Unable to update the comment xxx, you must be a creator of the comment to update it

Comment: Seems to be one the more common issues in DevOps/TFS: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-update-another-user-comment/1245973

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue.

Delete comment feature is now no longer supported in azure devops because in recent time azure devops architecture has been changed due to that it is not providing
comment id to each and every comment hence it's not possible to distinguished each and every comment and because of this issue deleting comment is not supported by azure devops.
unfortunately in the azure devops docs it's not updated yet.

I hope this will be helpful.